# Adding contents to default customer sign up / create account page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, template, customer-account

I would like to add a banner image and some contents to default create customer account page at `www.domain.com/customer/account/create/`, how do i do it? Or Can I add a CMS Page or static block to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my opinion easiest way is the use of `widget`.

Create a static block with content you want to show.

Now create a widget with:

**Type** : CMS static Block

**Display On** : Specific Page

**Page**: Customer Account Registration Form

**Container** choose from available

Hope above will help!

Comment: this works great, thank you!

Comment: welcome @KrisWen :)

Answer (score 2):

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- PHTML -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my.customer.informations" template="Magento_Customer::html/extra_informations.phtml" before="customer_form_register" />
            <!-- BLOCK CMS -->
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.extra.info" before="customer_form_register">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">info</argument> <!--info = cms block identifier -->
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Customer/templates/html/extra_informations.phtml

```
<?= __("Here is my content, cool !"); ?>
```